# Are trivia questions about facts acceptable?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Are trivia questions about facts acceptable?

For e.g.

- Who is the first player to do so?
- Which team did this first?

Also, if we already know such facts is it okay to ask & answer? (However if such questions are acceptable, it is totally okay to ask & answer IMO.)